# GET request not working when using Rest Template

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, request, postman

I'm trying to send a `GET` request using `RestTemplate` from `Spring` but for some reason when I execute `restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, String.class)` my response comes like this:

```
"\r\n"
```

Status code is 200 OK.
However, if I send the same request to the same link using Postman, the response body comes as it should be.

What am I doing wrong, and why is my response body looking like this?
Here is the code I am using:

```
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, String.class);
        System.out.println(responseEntity);
```

Comment: Try to add `httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
`

Comment: Same result. It is a limit for the response body? It is very big indeed in Postman.

Comment: I do not see set headers for request - something like this `HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
    url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class, param);`

Answer (score 0):

Set headers for request:

```
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
httpHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XM‌​L));
HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
    url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: Same problem. Response body comes as "\r\n". Maybe the length of the body is what is causing this?

Comment: Your response is `xml`? Maybe add   `restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new SimpleXmlHttpMessageConverter());`

Comment: Or simple: String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);

Comment: Still nothing. Even if I paste the url link in browser the response body is displayed fine.